# GraphQL - show list or single object

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I have managed to get following data through GraphQL:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "city": {
      "name": "Eldorado",
      "users": [
        {
          "username": "lgraham1"
        },
        {
          "username": "ehowell"
        },
        {
          "username": "cbauch"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have QueryType, CityType and UserType. In my QueryType I fetch city and display users by GraphQLList(UserType). What should I do if I want to display single user if there is an id provided?

My API looks like this:

```
all cities:
  /cities/

single city:
  /cities/:city_id

users for particular city:
  /cities/:city_id/users

single user:
  /cities/:city_id/users/:user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a `user` query to your main Query object.

Assuming your `id` is an `Integer`, you would do this

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQuery',
  fields: {
    // ...
    user: {
      type: User,
      args: {
        id: {
          type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
        }
      },
      resolve: function(rootValue, args) {
        return db.users.findOne(args)
      }
    }
  }
})

const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: Query,
  // ...
});
```

Then you can query using

```
{
  user (id: 12345) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or you could make a function

```
query findUser ($id: Int!) {
  user (id: $id) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I added user query to my `CityType` Object, not to my main `Query` Object. It works, but I hard coded the fetch url, because I don't know how to pass city_id to my `UserType`. My url for single user looks like this: `/cities/:city_id/users/:user_id`

Comment: You would just add `city_id` as another argument to the query. Then use `user(cityId: $city_id, id: $id)` – both params would be available in `args` so you can still just do `db.users.findOne(args)`.